# Gigabyte motherboard (890gpa-ud3h) won't shutdown USB power

Tags: bios, shutdown, acpi

what the thing the Gigabyte engineers were thinking about their BIOS? How to disable USB being powered while standby/off by button?

If I do hard shutdown by button (not related to my another question about hdds, more like to kernel testing), USB still has its power -> my usb mouse has its case mod light -> I have to wake up and turn off AC power. >_<

However, software shutdown is OK - usb is powered off. In BIOS, no "wake on something" is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it's not bug. It's a feature. Check you motherboard's manual. There is probably a jumper setting which controls that behavior. (after consulting manual, there seems to be no jumper option to disable USB power)

Motherboard's [website](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3420#ov) too claims that this is a feature.

You could try with setting ErP to disabled, if it's enabled.

If that doesn't work, my only idea is to try with On/Off Charge Support utility and see what it offers. If that too doesn't work, contact Gigabyte.